# Which floor is the Hogwarts Library on?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Is there any text in any of the Harry Potter books that identifies which floor of Hogwarts Castle the entrance to the Library is located in?

Answer (score 31):

**First Floor. (Second Floor in American-speak.)**

It is one floor below the entrance to Dumbledore's office, which is on the second floor.

- ***Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*** - Page 557

  > Harry tore up the stone steps, through the oak front doors and off up
  >   the marble staircase **towards the *second* floor**. Five minutes later,
  >   he was hurtling toward a **stone gargoyle** standing halfway along an
  >   empty corridor. "Sher --sherbet lemon!" he panted at it. This was the
  >   password to the hidden staircase to **Dumbledore's office**...
- ***Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*** - Page 150

  > [Harry] turned on his heel and stormed **out of the library**, earning
  >   himself a reproving glare from Madam Pince, who was polishing the
  >   gilded cover of a large spellbook. Harry **blundered up the corridor**...
- ***Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*** - Page 151

  > Harry **stamped up the stairs and turned along another corridor**,
  >   which was particularly dark; the torches had been extinguished by a
  >   strong, icy draught which was blowing through a loose window pane. He
  >   was **halfway down the passage**...
- ***Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets*** - Page 152

  > They marched in silence **around a corner** and she stopped before a
  >   large and extremely ugly **stone gargoyle**.

Comment: Does this take into account the moving stairs? The second source doesn't make it explicitely clear and the first is from a fan wiki.

Comment: @Parrotmaster According to the depict done in "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", the stairs can move to connect different corridors but always between the same two floors, so the connections seem to hold. But that sounds like a good question on its own.

Comment: @bracco23 Thanks for clarifying, I didn't know that bit of information.

Comment: A note for any US readers: this means the library is _one floor above ground level_, since in the UK the lowest non-basement floor is called the "Ground Floor", then the floors above are 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc.

Comment: This answer could be improved by getting rid of the two hp wiki block quotes and instead citing the relevant passages from the actual Harry Potter books.